# Cox regression hazard ratio (group 1 vs. group 4) changes calculation changes after combining group 2 and 3?

Tags: cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

I am working on a project which involves fitting a Cox proportional hazard model to a time to event situation in SAS. We have the variables:

1. y - event or censor (0/1)
2. timeto - time to event y
3. x - categorical variable that takes the value (1,2,3,4) which represents group 1,2,3,4

The SAS code I am using is:

```
proc phreg data=data1;
class x;
model timeto*y(0) = x / ties=efron rl;
hazardratio x / diff=all;
run;
```

I would then get the desired hazard ratios (HR) outputs for

- group 1 vs. 2
- group 1 vs. 3
- group 1 vs. 4 (this is the HR of interest, HR=0.5151, let's say)
- group 2 vs. 3
- group 2 vs. 4
- group 3 vs. 4

Then when I was asked to combine group 2 and 3 for simplicity purpose. So I did a simple data step:

```
data data1;
set data1;
if x=2 then x=3; *simply put all group 2 observations to group 3;
run;
```

Then when I run the proc phreg code again, I get the HR outputs

- group 1 vs. 3
- group 1 vs. 4 (this becomes different, HR=0.4988)
- group 3 vs. 4

From what I understand the HR for group 1 vs group 4 should not change based on the formula in https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/statug/statug_phreg_details24.htm.

I am not an expert, and I really wonder why the HR changes after regrouping. Might someone be willing to explain to me?

Comment: The method for calculating the HR between two groups does not change, but the model will estimate new parameters (ie, coefficients) if any aspect of the regression equation changes. This includes recoding a variable, dropping a groups of observations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Following Therneau and Grambsch, Equation 3.4 of [Modeling Survival Data--Extending the Cox Model](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) (Springer, 2000), if there are no tied event times the score equation solved to estimate the parameter-value vector $\theta$ is:

$$ U(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^{\infty} \left[X_i(s) - \bar x(\theta,s)\right] dN_i(s) = \sum_{i=1}^n U_i(\theta)$$

where $dN_i(s)$ is 1 if case $i$ has an event at time $s$ and 0 otherwise, $X_i$ represents the covariate values for case $i$ and $\bar x$ is a risk-weighted mean of $X$ over observations at risk:

$$\bar x(\theta,s) = \frac{\sum Y_i(s) r_i(s)X_i(s)}{\sum Y_i(s) r_i(s)}.
$$

Here, $Y_i(s)$ is the at-risk indicator for cases at time $s$ and the risk-weighting is $r_i(\theta,s) =\exp[\theta' X_i(s)]$.

When you group 2 dummy variables into 1, you thus are changing the score equations solved to obtain the Cox model coefficients. With the nonlinearity introduced by the exponentiation needed to calculate the risk-weighted average, combining your original groups 2 and 3 together could change the corresponding risk-weighted covariate averages and thus the estimates of the other coefficients.